# McDuck Frankenstein Movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, disney, donald-duck, scrooge-mcduck

I'm trying to identify a Disney movie that involves Donald Duck or the Scrooge McDuck family of characters.

They rent a castle, and end up awakening Frankenstein. There's also a story involving a blob monster? It could be an anthology on VHS, or a full movie, I'm not sure.

I remember in the pre-video ads that there was an ad for Disney parks with the villain characters in their park costumes.

I believe it's a 90's VHS, though it could have come out anywhere between the 90's and early 00's.

Comment: The duck wasn’t a vampire duck, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you might be referring to the [Disney Television compilation video](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Disney_Television_compilation_videos), **"[Monster Bash](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14480460/?ref_=tt_trv_cnn)"**, released in 1993.

The compilation included an episode of *[Goof Troop](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103428/)* titled "[Frankengoof](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1732874/)" (1992).

From IMDB:

> Goofy inherits the his family's scary Frankengoof castle. Along with the castle there is also a monster included. Pete tries to scare Goofy by pretending to be the monster.

It also included an episode of *[DuckTales](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092345/)* titled "[Ducky Horror Picture Show](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1052574/?ref_=ttmc_mc_tt)" (1987).

From IMDB:

> Werewolf, Dracula, and other monsters come to Duckburg for an annual convention, wreaking havoc on the town and on Scrooge McDuck.

The [IMDB movie connections page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1052574/movieconnections/) for the latter episode mentions that it featured a version of the Blob (from [the 1958 movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/) starring Steve McQueen), along with several other famous monster movie characters.

> The Blob (1958)
>
> The Blob attends the monster party.

Both episodes can be viewed on YouTube.

*Goof Troop*: "Frankengoof":

*DuckTales*: "Ducky Horror Picture Show":

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you so much!